# Unable to infer complex closure return type swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to post data to the list but keep getting the error 'Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate'
how do I fix this?

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [Post] = [Post]()
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    @State private var searchTerm: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print(searchTerm)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List { // ERROR SHOWS UP HERE
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
            ForEach(data) { post in
                Text(post.fullname ?? "null")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.reload()
        }
        .onReceive(self.networkManager.posts, perform: { _ in
            self.reload()
        })
    }

    private func reload() {
        networkManager.fetchData(playerName: "messi")
        self.data = networkManager.posts
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `NetworkManage.posts` is `@Published` property the subscriber in view have to be specified as follow

```
.onReceive(self.networkManager.$posts, perform: {_ in    // << fixed !!
    self.reload()
})
```

Note: btw, `didSet` does not work for `@State`, so don't spend time on that.